# Ruby bundler: use gem from mercurial repository

Tags: ruby, mercurial, bundler

As everyone know, we can use gem from git repository:

```
gem 'nokogiri', :git => 'git://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri.git', :branch => '1.4'
```

*(example from http://bundler.io/gemfile.html)*

But I prefer Mercurial, so is it possible to use gem from Mercurial repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no, however there has been some activity to add it. The most recent seems to be [Bundler Issue #1219](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/1219).

The work around I would go with would be to either clone locally and use the file path in the Gemfile. Perhaps using Ryan Bigg's nifty [Bundler Local Paths Trick](http://ryanbigg.com/2013/08/bundler-local-paths/) on the development system. Unfortunately this is not a good solution for deploying.

Hopefully the bundler team will merge in support at some point.